# Chef : Define an attribute with the value of another attribute

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-attributes

In my environment file, I have defined an attribute say

['app']['web'] = 'nginx'

and in another environment file

['app']['web'] = 'apache'

My intention is to create a recipe which will run on any environment. Inside the recipe I'm defining one attribute. So while running this recipe in the first environment I want to define node.default['cluster']**['nginx']**['endpoint'] and in second environment it should be node.default['cluster']**['apache']**['endpoint']

I used the following

node.default['cluster']**[node['app']['web']]**['endpoint']

But this is not working. Is there any way I can achieve this ?

Comment: The above code will work. Actually I made a spelling mistake in the node.default['cluster'][node['app']['web']]['endpoint'] and that's the reason chef-client was failed.

Answer (score 0):

it is hard to give you a concrete answer since you did not specify the attribute [type](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-types). the attribute type in conjunction with the attribute [precedence](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-precedence) will determine whether `node['app']['web']` holds non nil value at the chef-client [compilation phase](https://docs.chef.io/chef_client_overview.html#the-chef-client-run)

Comment: I added it as default attribute in environment file.
"default_attributes": {
    "app": {
      "web": "nginx"
    }

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/poise/poise-derived for a solution. More characters because I have to.